# Java Generics, Implementing an Interface of Type Iterable<E>

Tags: java, generics

I have two "Sets": one is a class, `GenericSet`, the other is an interface, `ISet`. `class GenericSet implements ISet`. The class signatures are as follows:

```
interface ISet<E entends Iterable<E>> { .... }
```

The idea - of course - is that the interface defines some methods I want to see implemented by the implementing class, `GenericSet`, whose signature follows (here's where I am stuck):

```
class GenericSet<E extends Iterable<E> implements ISet<Iterable<<E>> { .... }
```

I get the warning:

> Bound mismatch: The type Iterable is not a valid substitute for the bounded > parameter > of the type ISet

The general idea of class `GenericSet` is that - while implementing `ISet` - it is able to facilitate the receipt of many types of objects, creating a set of the received type.

What am I missing? I know the error message explains it; however, as I am new to Generics, I don't understand what would be a "valid substitute" for the bounded parameter.

Comment: Do your code fragments compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the issue is that `ISet` doesn't *also* `extend Iterable` like

```
public interface ISet<E extends Iterable<E>> extends Iterable<E> {
}
```

That way it satisfies the condition of also being an `Iterable`.

Also, I think you meant

```
class GenericSet<E extends Iterable<E>> implements ISet<E> {

}
```

which is then presumably used to implement an `Iterable` `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this varies a bit from the accepted answer; however, depending upon the implementation details, the following also works:

```
public interface ISet<E extends Iterable<E>> { .... }
```

Against

```
class GenericSet<E extends Iterable<E>> implements ISet<E> { .... }
```

The smallest difference, here, being in the signature of the interface.